# Downloading json from web service works only when i debug

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-service

I created an application in adroid which suppose to download some data, from json that I put on my webservice, according to certain schedule. I set AlarmManager to fire service which contains async task that takes care of connecting to the internet and downloading json. Strange thing is that when I debug the application everything works fine, but when I run it not in debug mode I get :

> java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "`<host address of my web app>`": No address associated with hostname

Can You tell me why everything works fine only when I debug?

**EDIT:**

In this method i call async task

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    try {
        dataSwitch.setMobileDataEnabled(true, this);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /*GETTING PATIENT ID AND SCHEDULE FORM SHARED PREFERENCES*/
    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    editor = prefs.edit();
    patientId = prefs.getLong("patientId", -1);
    schedule = prefs.getString("schedule", null);
    numberOfEvents = prefs.getInt("numberOfEvents", -1);
    credentials = prefs.getString("credentials", null);
    /* CHECKING IF PATIENT ID IS SET*/
    if (patientId != -1 && credentials!=null) {


        isLoginCorrect = true;
        /*STARTING ASYNC TASK*/
        new CheckUpdateAsync().execute();


    } else {

        Toast.makeText(context, "NO PATIENT SELECTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        stopSelf();
    }

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

}
```

This is part of my async task where I open the connection:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected ListOfPatients doInBackground(Void... params) {

        HttpURLConnection connection;
        ListOfPatients patients;
        final String url = getString(R.string.url_of_webapp);
        try {
             /*LOGIN USING HTTP URL CONNECTION*/
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url + "j_spring_security_check").openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            try (OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream()) {
                output.write(credentials.getBytes(charset));
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
              /*CHECKING IF STARTING PAGE WAS LOADED*/
                if (!connection.getURL().toString().equals(url + "user/start")) {
                    isLoginCorrect = false;

                }
                output.flush();
                output.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**EDIT2**
Here is my gradle build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    packagingOptions {

    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'

    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.szymon.vibrationmeasureservice"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')



compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'
compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.0'

compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.6.0'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.0'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.0'


}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, put the lines where you call the webservices, thanks.

Comment: do you have a debug configuration set up, but not one for runtime?

Comment: also paste gradle build file

Comment: I made some change. Instead of Service with async task to connect to the internet I used Intent Service and put connection to onHandleIntent method but still getting the same error and it still doesnt ocurre during debugging.

Comment: Is the hostname used when using the debug Vs normal build the same? 

And do you use Proguard for the normal build?

Can you try switching proguard off (just a hunch).

Comment: Have you taken a look at networking libraries like [Google's Volley networking library](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) or [Square's Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)? They make networking so much easier and you can forget about using AsyncTask completely.

Comment: @DeepakBala Yes hostname is the same all the time, I put it in values/string in res package. I commented proguard in gradle build and nothing have changed (btw. I have default proguard file).

Comment: @FMontano Thanks for the advice I will check this libraries out, but my point is to get to know why exactly my code only works when i debug.

Comment: Ok I managed to solve this problem on my own. It seems like my method ` dataSwitch.setMobileDataEnabled(true, this);` in which I turn on data transfer is too slow so rest of the code is executing when data isn't on yet. I have added condition that checks if internet connection is availible before executing rest of the code
and it worked like a charm. Thanks anyways for trying to help.